# open maps/google maps in react native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, maps

I am trying to open google maps or maps in my `react-native` application.

When I run the app on my iPhone/simulator, I receive this error

```
"Don't know how to open URI:...".
```

What I am doing wrong?

My code:

```js
    openGps() {
      var url = 'geo:37.484847,-122.148386'
      this.openExternalApp(url)
    }
    
    openExternalApp(url) {
      Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
          Linking.openURL(url);
        } else {
          console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + url);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: is there a similar way to open camera app?

Answer (score 256):

To open url with custom label ios/android:

```js
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps://0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
const label = 'Custom Label';
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
  android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});

    
Linking.openURL(url);
```

Comment: This solution is so clean! Thank you for the `label` component!

Comment: change like this const scheme = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'maps:0,0?q=' : 'geo:0,0?q=';

Comment: on google maps the marker's name is the coordinates and not the label :/

Comment: is it possible to add custom label to android?

Comment: There's a nice library to do all of this and more: https://github.com/tschoffelen/react-native-map-link.

Comment: scheme is in wrong format. You have to replace zeroS with lat and lon. This way it produces "geo:0,0?q=41.04481,28.9976903(address)". lat and lon should be on the point at zeroS

Comment: how to sent a source and destination with navigation on,the above answer is correct,it does the functionality

Comment: can i give params like i need to show my map on driving mode not on walking mode ? @Narek Ghazaryan

Comment: is there a way to show the direction name on google maps instead of the coordinates, at least on ios, you can show the custom label but on android it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I had to do `label = encodeURIComponent(label)` to support spaces on iOS

Comment: I just wanted to mention that this code broke for iOS after updating to RN 0.71.7 and I was able to fix the issue by adding `//` to `ios: 'maps://0,0?q='`

Comment: @Amir5000 Came here for the same issue, thanks for this it was a lifesaver!

Comment: @Amir5000 Thanks!! It was breaking in ios without // and adding ios: 'maps://0,0?q=' works perfect

Answer (score 26):

```
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `maps:0,0?q=${fullAddress}`,
  android: `geo:0,0?q=${fullAddress}`,
})

Linking.openURL(url)
```

Comment: I'd excuse @pragnesh for this - it's a clean, self-explanatory and actually working code.

Comment: too easy! so clean @Pragnesh

Answer (score 25):

you can do like this:

Android:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('google.navigation:q=100+101')}>
```

where `q` is the destination lat + long

IOS:

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('maps://app?saddr=100+101&daddr=100+102')}>
```

where `saddr` is start address and `daddr` is destination address lat+long

Comment: Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation

Comment: Thanks, DEV for the solution!

Comment: Basically you can add just daddr for IOS. This might be taken your current location and directing you to daddr location. Thanks for answer btw! <3

Answer (score 23):

This is because iOS does not yet have support for `geo:` yet as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747570/geo-protocol-on-iphone-safari). What you can do is detect the OS and:

- use `geo:` on Android
- handle iOS differently. Possibly use `maps:` as it will open up Apple Maps, though I'm unsure how to properly send the coordinates to it. Or maybe append it to a google maps HTTP URL and open it in the browser.

For [example](https://snack.expo.io/S1nAyhWpe), your `openGps` function could look like this:

```js
openGps = (lat, lng) => {
  var scheme = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'maps:' : 'geo:';
  var url = scheme + `${lat},${lng}`;
  Linking.openURL(url);
}
```

Comment: You can also use `http://maps.apple.com/?ll=<lat>,<long>` or `http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=<lat>,<long>` to start a navigation.

Answer (score 13):

```
const latitude = "40.7127753";
const longitude = "-74.0059728";
const label = "New York, NY, USA";

const url = Platform.select({
  ios: "maps:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label,
  android: "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label
});
Linking.openURL(url);
```

or **with checking if there's a google map app on device** and if not open the location in browser

```
const latitude = "40.7127753";
const longitude = "-74.0059728";
const label = "New York, NY, USA";

const url = Platform.select({
  ios: "maps:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label,
  android: "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label
});

Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
  if (supported) {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
  } else {
    const browser_url =
      "https://www.google.de/maps/@" +
      latitude +
      "," +
      longitude +
      "?q=" +
      label;
    return Linking.openURL(browser_url);
  }
});
```

Comment: With this answer the map opens along with custom label which is a good thing.
But a major issue in this approach is that if I have multiple addresses with same block names in different cities then no matter which lat long I provide, it always takes me to the first city with the given block name. If there is a fix for that then this would be a good solution.

Comment: This just search apple maps and google maps for the label and ignores the coordinates.

Answer (score 10):

Working on Android with an address using the following:

```
Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=address');
```

Replace `address` with your favourite address.

Answer (score 4):

To complement other answers, here's a snippet of adding a marker on Android:

```
    const location = `${latitude},${longitude}`
    const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `maps:${location}`,
      android: `geo:${location}?center=${location}&q=${location}&z=16`,
    });
    Linking.openURL(url);
```

If you want more details about Android and google maps, here's the link for the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Answer (score 4):

For apple maps direction with coordinate like this

```
Linking.openURL(`maps://app?daddr=${latitude},${longitude}&dirflg=d&t=m`)
```

dirflg = The transport type.

1. d (by car)
2. w (by foot)
3. r (by public transit)

t = map type
m standart view

daddr = destination address

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this solution and it's working

```
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
const label = 'Custom Label';
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
  android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});
```

Linking.openURL(url);

Comment: Where is the difference to this already given answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006762/1574221)?

Comment: I don't have the right to upvote it because I'm new that's why I did this to let them know it is working

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation in [Apple Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html), a little changes from @Narek Ghazaryan's answer.
This is due to apple maps will query on provided "label" first. If the label or store name do not exist, it will show nothing.

So we need to add a parameter as "ll" to specify current location with the provided label / store name.

```
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
const label = 'Custom Label';
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `${scheme}${label}&ll=${latLng}`,
  android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [react-native-map-link](https://github.com/tschoffelen/react-native-map-link) lib. It opens a bottom sheet with desired options

```
import { showLocation } from 'react-native-map-link'

showLocation({
    latitude: 38.8976763,
    longitude: -77.0387185,
    sourceLatitude: -8.0870631,  // optionally specify starting location for directions
    sourceLongitude: -34.8941619,  // not optional if sourceLatitude is specified
    title: 'The White House',  // optional
    googleForceLatLon: false,  // optionally force GoogleMaps to use the latlon for the query instead of the title
    googlePlaceId: 'ChIJGVtI4by3t4kRr51d_Qm_x58',  // optionally specify the google-place-id
    alwaysIncludeGoogle: true, // optional, true will always add Google Maps to iOS and open in Safari, even if app is not installed (default: false)
    dialogTitle: 'This is the dialog Title', // optional (default: 'Open in Maps')
    dialogMessage: 'This is the amazing dialog Message', // optional (default: 'What app would you like to use?')
    cancelText: 'This is the cancel button text', // optional (default: 'Cancel')
    appsWhiteList: ['google-maps'] // optionally you can set which apps to show (default: will show all supported apps installed on device)
    // appTitles: { 'google-maps': 'My custom Google Maps title' } // optionally you can override default app titles
    // app: 'uber'  // optionally specify specific app to use
})
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of oma's answer, I came up with this. For the ios version, I directly wrote googleMaps instead of maps because it did not work. This is given that Google Maps is installed on the device and I tested this with a physical device. If its not installed it will go into the store. It works perfectly while starting the navigation too.

```
<Button
  hasText
  transparent
  onPress={() =>
    Linking.openURL(
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? 'googleMaps://app?saddr=6.931970+79.857750&daddr=6.909877+79.848521'
        : 'google.navigation:q=6.909877+79.848521',
    )
 }>
    <Text>Open Maps</Text>
 </Button>
```

FYI - Im using the Button component from the Native Base library.

Comment: How can I add more location to ios url?  there is "waypoints" to redirect to browser but its not working for redirecting to app

Comment: one problem here is that on ios the from and the to coordinates are the same

Answer (score 2):

For google map/Map direction, you can use this code

```
const latitude = "30.3753";
const longitude = "69.3451";
const openMapDirection = () => {
    const url: any = Platform.select({
      ios: `comgooglemaps://?center=${latitude},${longitude}&q=${latitude},${longitude}&zoom=14&views=traffic"`,
      android: `geo://?q=${latitude},${longitude}`,
    });
    Linking.canOpenURL(url)
      .then((supported) => {
        if (supported) {
          return Linking.openURL(url);
        } else {
          const browser_url = `https://www.google.de/maps/@${latitude},${longitude}`;
          return Linking.openURL(browser_url);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          Linking.openURL(
            `maps://?q=${latitude},${longitude}`,
          );
        }
      });
  };
```

**Note**: For open google map on **IOS** you have to add this in `info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
   <string>comgooglemaps</string>
  </array>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution and i keep getting Unsupported link

Answer (score 2):

I have created a separate component for **store location** and full code is as under.

**Component code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Pressable, Platform, Linking } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import Text from "../Text";

const StoreLocation = ({}) => {

  /**
   * method to open google map
   */
  const openMap = () => {
    const latitude = 33.189368147027565; // latitude of your desire location
    const longitude = 73.35574341458842; // longitude of your desire location
    const scheme = Platform.select({
      ios: "maps:0,0?q=",  // if device is ios 
      android: "geo:0,0?q=", // if device is android 
    });
    const latLng = `${latitude},${longitude}`;
    const label = "your own label";
    const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
      android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
    });

    Linking.openURL(url);
  };

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={() => openMap()} style={styles.mapView}>
      <View>
        <Text>Open Map</Text>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default StoreLocation;
```

if you only want to use method just copy **openMap()** method and change your desired **longitude**, **latitude** & **label** to use this method according to your app.

**tested on Android**

Answer (score 1):

I think [react-native-launch-navigator](https://github.com/dpa99c/react-native-launch-navigator) module is a much cleaner way of doing this. Then it is simple as `LaunchNavigator.navigate([50.279306, -5.163158], {start: "50.342847, -4.749904"})
   .then(() => console.log("Launched navigator"))
    .catch((err) =>console.error("Error launching navigator: "+err));`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest way to navigate from your app to Google Maps

```
const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=lat,long&dir_action=navigate`
Linking.openURL(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this solution

```
Linking.openURL(`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${startPlace.latitude},${startPlace.longitude}&destination=${endPlace.latitude},${endPlace.longitude}`)
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#map-action

Answer (score 0):

```
> enter code hereconst location = `${latitude},${longitude}`
>       const url = Platform.select({
>      // YOU CAN CHECK FOR IOS ASWELL
>         android: `geo:${location}?center=${location}&q=${location}&z=16`,
>       });
>       Linking.openURL(url);
```

Answer (score -2):

This Will work....

```
const lat = "12.914490",
const lng = "77.666512",
const lable = "Any Title",

const scheme = Platform.OS === "android" ? "geo:0,0?q=" : "maps:0,0?q=";
var latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
var label = lable;

const url = Platform.select({
   ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
   android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
});

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Downvoted just because its the same as the other answers only a bit less clean