# How To render the directions when Linking Google maps App in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

I want to render the directions between tow point (current location, passed location)

I'm using Linking to open the Google Maps App when clicking the button I passed the (lat, long), I want to see in the map.

so just when the Maps App open they get me to the Location I passed without display the destination between my current location and other address and without any Markers, any idea how to solve these?

[image: maps]

Here is my Code

```
_openMap = () => {
        const { region } = this.state;
        console.log('open directions');
        // Linking.openURL('geo:37.484847,-122.148386');
        Linking.canOpenURL(`geo:${region.latitude},${region.longitude}`).then(supported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(`geo:${region.latitude},${region.longitude}`);
            } else {
                alert('sorry invalid url')
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: may be a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214062/open-maps-google-maps-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either:

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address
```

or

```
google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation

Comment: Great, Thank you