# Launching Google Maps app from react-native-maps

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm displaying dynamic maps inside my app using using react-native-maps. I want Google Maps app to launch when a user presses some part of map, a text or an icon, so they can view the map also externally. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

```
  <MapView
    showsUserLocation
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: placesLat,
      longitude: placesLng,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0022,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0121
    }}
  >
    <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={{ latitude: placesLat, longitude: placesLng }}
      title={placesTitle}
    />
  </MapView>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onMapPress` function prop to `MapView.Marker` component and call Linking.openUrl as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214062/open-maps-google-maps-in-react-native)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much. :) As only change I had to put onPress instead of onMapPress.