# How to open google map with latitude and longitude

Tags: react-native

I have latitude and longitude values and on click of direction icon I want to open map with marker and if map application is not available in phone then want to navigate to play store, please let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: can you tell me whats not working properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open maps/google maps in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214062/open-maps-google-maps-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the geo/maps link like this:

```js
  const openAddressOnMap = (label, lat, lng) => {
    const scheme = Platform.select({
      ios: 'maps:0,0?q=',
      android: 'geo:0,0?q=',
    });
    const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
    const label = label;
    const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
      android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
    });
    Linking.openURL(url);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the `expo-linking` package. Check the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/) for instructions on how to install and use. Even if you don't use Expo yet, you can use their SDKs by adding their base package (see [this](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/)). As the docs say, if you want the additional functionality of directing the user to the Play store if Google Maps is not installed, you'll also need the `react-native-app-link` package.

Once you have the package installed you'll need to use the linking scheme provided by Google Maps, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started)

Comment: I am using Linking of react-native but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

as per Narevs answer in another post

You can try this below

```
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
const label = 'Custom Label';
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
  android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});

    
Linking.openURL(url);
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts