# Is Geo: Protocol on iPhone still broken after 9 years?

Tags: ios

This question [Geo: Protocol on iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747570/geo-protocol-on-iphone-safari) is 9 years old.

Is there not a solution for this yet?

I'm sending a geo uri with pushover; it doesn't work on an unspecified iphone.

EDIT:
It appears that it's possible for an ios-app to register its own uri scheme, like chess: for instance.

Why haven't any mapping app done that for loc: ?

I wonder if it's possible to make an app which registers loc: and then hand the request over to an app of the users choice.

Comment: "Broken" implies supported but not working. I think the real situation is "not supported". It seems likely that support will never be added

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that it's possible for an ios-app to register its own uri scheme, like chess: for instance.

Yes, and some do. For example, URI's with the `geo:` scheme work fine if you have Google Earth installed. There may be other apps that also support it.

> Why haven't any mapping app done that for loc: ?

`loc:` doesn't appear on [IANA's list of well-known URI schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml#uri-schemes-1). I'll guess that that's a typo and you actually meant `geo:`, in which case the answer is that at least one app *has*, in fact, registered `geo:`. Schemes don't have to be on IANA's list to be supported, of course, so it's also possible that there are apps out there that support `loc:` as a scheme.